# How to embed an apps script into a third-party site through an iframe so that the iframe dynamically changes its height depending on the content?

Tags: google-apps-script, iframe, iframe-resizer

I'm trying to use the [iframe-resizer](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer) library to automatically adjust the height of my iframe according to the content, but I get an error:
iframeResizer.js:134 [iFrameSizer][Nested host page: myIframe] IFrame has not responded within 5 seconds. Check iFrameResizer.contentWindow.js has been loaded in iFrame. This message can be ignored if everything is working, or you can set the warningTimeout option to a higher value or zero to suppress this warning.

How can you solve the problem?
[link to my error page](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbw7AVEUC5dwwivMGkVaRkfWZz3IT2kPTQM0-agtcbRauiTBmm-A/exec)

Here is what i added to the top of the child page:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iframe-resizer/4.1.1/iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js"></script>
```

This is what I added to the parent page:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iframe-resizer/4.1.1/iframeResizer.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe id="myIframe" src="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbw92jqTb6uKu8V63EfHDxmtahkz35ld1MLS4mR-PxcsVzH0fQhe/exec" width="100%" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#myIframe').on('load', event => {
      iFrameResize({ log: true }, '#myIframe')
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the file that the error message mentions in the iframe